# Overriding Fosuser profile form's label

Tags: php, forms, symfony, label, fosuserbundle

I write a formtype extends the forsuser ProfileFormType, but everytime I rendered it in template, there should be always a label "User" appear in top of form. I figured out it comes form original fosuser ProfileFormType:

```
namespace FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type;
use .....
class ProfileFormType extends AbstractType
{

private $class;

/**
 * @param string $class The User class name
 */
public function __construct($class)
{
    $this->class = $class;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $child = $builder->create('user', 'form', array('data_class' => $this->class));
    $this->buildUserForm($child, $options);

    .......
```

if I add the attribute for this form field like:

```
$child = $builder->create('user', 'form', array('label'=>'some info','data_class' => $this->class));
```

it could be worked, but its bad for modify the original files, how can I modify it in my custom formtype or in template when rendering?

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend the `FOSUserBundle` by creating your own `UserBundle` and within the Bundle class add:

```
public function getParent()
{
    return 'FOSUserBundle';
}
```

Then create Form/Type directory and create a new form type called `ProfileFormType` and within that new form type place:

```
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Form\Type;  

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface; 
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;  

class ProfileFormType extends BaseType {     

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)     
{         
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);         

    // add your custom field        
    $builder->add('name');    
}      

public function getName()     
{         
    return 'acme_user_profile';     
}
```

After that you need to add the new form to the service like:

```
<services>         
     <service id="acme_user.profile.form.type" class="Acme\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType">
         <tag name="form.type" alias="acme_user_profile" />             
         <argument>%fos_user.model.user.class%</argument>         
     </service>      
 </services>
```

Finally add this to your config.yml:

```
fos_user:     
    # ...     
    profile:       
        form:          
            type: acme_user_profile
```

Remember to replace `acme` with your current structure information.

More information can be found at: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md

Comment: y, I knew it, I've already created my formtype extended fosuser, my question is exactly that how to override parent's label (ex.child 'user' in parent class)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override only labels, just add a FOSUserBundle.xx.yml file in `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/translations` directory. No need to override the whole bundle, even if it could the proper for further overrides...

If you already have overrode FOSUserBundle, add the file in `YourCustomFOSUserBundle/Resources/translations` !

Copy it from the `FOSUserBundle/Resources/translations/FOSUserBundle.xx.yml` you want to override, and modify translations. You should keep only modified translations in this file.

Comment: it didn't offer the translation option for the profile form above, I don't believe nobody encounter this problem, but I've searched around theres no answer! What I want just remove or customize the parent 'user' form label

Comment: for me , I just render form row manually to avoid this happend, it worked.

Comment: Of course, if you render the whole form with form_row(form), you'll get a label for the form itself... It's better to write form_row for each row, and sometimes, i use form_widget and form_errors only..